# CXF Logging & cn:checks are ignored when used with <context:annotation-config />

Tags: cxf, cname, spring-annotations, transactionmanager

The technologies I'm using are: Apache CXF, Spring 3.x, Struts 2.x and Hibernate 3.x

I'm facing a strange problem while TransactionManager with using Apache CXF. For my application I'm using **CXF logging** with my web-service and **CN:checknames to ignore certificates on the server**. When I deploy the application on server it works perfectly fine with logs being generated and certificates being ignored. But in the second step I'm developing a front-end for different areas of the application thus configuring **annotation driven transaction manager** in the application.xml. But when ever I try to use this line `<context:annotation-config/>` the CXF starts generating different logging scheme and CN:check is completely ignored.

Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your getting two instances of service/proxy bean constructed. It's hard to say without seeing your complete Spring configuration, especially any component scans. I suggest putting a log statement in it's constructor to see if it is the case. If so, ensure there is only one component scan active.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that. :s